# Use simple MVC Html.DropDownList to control visibility of a div, onLoad and on selectChange

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I have the following code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Intermediary Bank Required?:</label>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <p class="form-control-static">@Html.DropDownList("IntermediaryRequired",(SelectList)ViewBag.IntermediaryRequired,"NO", new { @class = "form-control" })</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**IntermediaryRequired** is a `bool` field on my model

I also have this Extension Helper:

```
public static class BooleanExtensions
{
    public static string ToYesNoString(this bool value)
    {
        return value ? "YES" : "NO";
    }
    public static string ToDislay(this bool value)
    {
        return value ? "normal" : "none";
    }
    public static string ToChar(this bool value)
    {
        return value ? "1" : "0";
    }
}
```

My aim is to hide/display a `<div>` in response to the selected value in the DropDownList for two cases:

1. when the user Manually changes the DropDownList selection
2. when the form loads with an existing value for the model field **IntermediaryRequired**

Please how can we achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a little bit of javascript. Listen to the `change` event of the dropdown, check the value  and hide/show the div. do the samething on `document.ready` (page loaded) as well to work with existing value of the model.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

  //On page load, update the visiblity
  var v=$("#IntermediaryRequired").val();
  UpdateDivVisibility(v);

  //When user changes the dropdown, update visibility
  $("#IntermediaryRequired").change(function(e){
    var v=$("#IntermediaryRequired").val();
    UpdateDivVisibility(v);
  });

});

function UpdateDivVisibility(isVisible)
{
    if(v=="YES") 
    {
      $("#DivIdtoHide").show();
    }
    else
    {
       $("#DivIdtoHide").hide();
    }
}
</script>
```

**EDIT** : *As per the question in the comment*

Usually I create a viewmodel like this

```
public class CreateCustomerVM
{
  public string Name { set;get;}
  public List<SelectListItem> IntermediaryOptions {set;get;}
  public string IntermediaryRequired {set;get;}

  public CreateCustomerVM()
  {
    this.IntermediaryOptions =new List<SelectListItem>() 
  }
}
```

and in your GET actions for create

```
public ActionResult create()
{
  var vm = new CreateCustomerVM();
  vm.IntermediaryOptions = GetOptions();
  return View(vm);
}
private List<SelectListItem> GetOptions()
{
    return new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem {Value = "0", Text = "No"},
        new SelectListItem {Value = "1", Text = "Yes"}
    };
}
```

And your view will be bounded to the viewmodel

```
@model CreateCustomerVM
@using(Html.Beginform())
{
  <div>
   <p>Required?</p>
   <p>@Html.DropdowListFor(s=>s.IntermediaryRequired,Model.IntermediaryOptions)
   <div id="ExtraOptions">
      <!-- Your additional UI elements here -->
   </div>
   <input type="submit" />
  </div>
}
```

In your Form post, you can read the `IntermediaryRequired` value and convert that to boolean value

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateCustomerVM model)
{
  //check model.IntermediaryRequired  
 // to do : Save and Redirect(PRG pattern)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Please can you help with the proper syntax for the `@Html.DropDownList("IntermediaryRequired")` I need the DropDown to show Yes/No while the field is a boolean. How can we do this with Html.DropDownList that is bound to a boolean model field IntermediaryRequired

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this to show/hide the `div` when the user Manually changes the Drop Down

```
var yourDiv = $('#yourDiv');
$('#IntermediaryRequired').on('change', function(){
    if ($(this).val() == 'YES') {
        yourDiv.show();
    }
    else {
        yourDiv.hide();
    }
});
```

And to get the same result on page load you can try

```
@if (Model.value)
{
    <div id="yourDiv">
       ....
    </div>
}
```

As a side note use `p` only when you want to add a *paragraph*, if you just want to add -*meaningless*- block element, you can use a `div`. You can read more about semantics [here](http://html5doctor.com/lets-talk-about-semantics/).

Comment: Thanks for that. Please can you help with the proper syntax for the `@Html.DropDownList("IntermediaryRequired")` I need the DropDown to show Yes/No while the field is a boolean. How can we do this with Html.DropDownList that is bound to a boolean model field IntermediaryRequired